# in Python, range(1, 100, *10) doesn't work?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I have a problem with `range()` or the for loop.

in C++, the for loop can be used like this:

```
for(int i=1;i<=100;i*=10){
 //lala
}
```

My Python script that causes the error looks like this:

```
li = [x for x in range(100, 0, /10)]

print(li)
```

I hope to get `li = [100, 10, 1]`

How can I achieve this without the use of `li.append ( 100, 10, 1 )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a generator expression, like

```
for i in (10 ** x for x in range(2, -1, -1)):
    print(i)
# 100
# 10
# 1
```

Or, if you want your "power range" to be a reusable function, you can create your own, i.e.

```
def powrange(*args, base=10):
    for i in range(*args):
        yield base ** i


for i in powrange(2, -1, -1, base=10):
    print(i)
# 100
# 10
# 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `range` for this. The third argument for range is a fixed step used to increment the value: it can't be used to multiply or divide the previous value.

Instead, use a `while` loop:

```
i = 1
while i < 100:
   ...
   i *= 10  # or i /= 10 depending on what you want.
```

If you *really* want to use a list comprehension, you can do as suggested by Albin Paul:

```
li = [10**x for x in range(3) ]  # [1, 10, 100]
li = [10**x for x in range(2, -1, -1)  # [100, 10, 1]
```

Comment: A lot of incorrect information in this post: You can use `range()` for this (you yourself are doing it), and if you do, you shouldn't use list comprehensions, but generator expressions, i.e. `(10**x for x in range(3))`

Comment: @NilsWerner no, what the OP wanted is a use of range with some "operator-parameters" (forgive the made up term) that control how the step is updated. That's what people meant when saying "you can't use range for this". Of course, transforming a range in order to obtain the desired output is the way to go, but it takes a different approach than just passing the correct parameters to a builtin function

Answer (score 1):

The built-in range is not meant to be used this way. It takes three arguments: `range(start, stop, step)` and goes from `start` to `stop` with a constant stepsize.

If you want to use a single function, you could use numpy's [logspace](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html)

It looks like this:

```
import numpy
li = numpy.logspace(0, 2, base=10, dtype = int)
# li is [1, 10, 100]
# goes from base^0 to base^2, so from 1 to 100
```

If you don't want to rely on numpy, the solution with a while loop seems very pythonic to me.

**Benchmark time :D**

A comment pointed out that this solution might be:

- non obvious
- slow

The first point is a matter of taste, but I disagree on performance:

```
reps = 100000
list_elems = 100

start = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(reps):
    np.logspace(0, list_elems, base=2, dtype=int)
end = time.perf_counter()
numpy_time = end - start


start = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(reps):
    [2**x for x in range(list_elems)]
end = time.perf_counter()
python_time = end - start

# reps = 100000
# list_elems = 100
# numpy took 1.70, python took 2.86

# reps = 100000
# list_elems = 10
# numpy took 1.65, python took 0.242
```

Of course, this depends a lot on the number of list elements that you want to produce. Numpy introduces overhead but scales better. So for shorter lists, python wins.

Comment: Using `numpy.logspace` for a loop variable is certainly not the most efficient and obvious way...

Comment: @NilsWerner, hm, I don't think I agree with you here. If you use numpy, the logspace function is a very obvious way to do it. And since I specified dtype = int, I'm not sure about the performance. For three elements it probably doesn't matter. But as soon as you want such a list with a few more items (probably not base 10 then :P ), numpy could be much more efficient ...

Answer (score 0):

To change make a `log(n)` time complexity loop you need the log function or use while loops to do the job

```
In [10]: import math
In [9]:  [10**x for x in range( 0,int(math.log10(1000)))]
Out[9]: [1, 10, 100]
```

I still think while loops are the way to go

Answer (score 0):

[The arguments for `range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) are: start, stop and step, where the step is int. 
Maybe you want to see the result as this:

```
li = [10**x for x in range(0, 3, 1)]
print(li)
```

> [1, 10, 100]

Overall take a look at a nice learning course, for example, "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python":

- [Here is the video right about loops](https://youtu.be/HFQGxh1jY3g)
- [And here is the whole
  course (available online for free)](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/#toc)

Answer (score -1):

When you use the for loop as 
`with x in range(start,stop,step)`

The way it takes place is that first

Edit: The first part is explanation why it won't work

1. You get a list generated by the range function(Not since python3 though), now it only returns a function range and its current state, this can be of float or int, so using `/10 as step` there will do nothing other than Invalid syntax, because range only accepts integers.
2. Only after this does x gets initialized and starts taking values present in the dictionary in an indexed way.

You can however use

`for y in range(2,-1,-1):
     x = (10**y)`

Welcome to python and happy coding.

Thanks to @GPhilo for pointing out the errors.

Comment: This is just plain wrong. Firstly, ever since python 3 `range` does not return a list of values. Secondly, `range` takes *integers* for all its parameters so passing `1/10` for anything won't work either. Lastly, your loop is never terminating because you'll never get 0 from iterating divisions.

Comment: And after your edit, the code is *still* wrong. If you were to try and run it you'd realize the syntax is wrong (you can't use `10**x` as the index of a for loop)

Comment: @GPhilo My bad, thanks for the suggests, made edits accordingly.